# JTextPane.setText(JTextPane.getText()) clear gaps in HTML mode

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

When I use JTextPane and type some text in HTML editor mode

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
//...
textPane.setText(textPane.getText());
```

Spaces at the beginning of lines are removed. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `&nbsp;` for adding spaces at the beginning with text/html content type. 
This link describe approachs how add spaces in html: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/qt/spaces-in-html.htm You can use one of them.